# How to make sure that the interface between stored procedures and the calling client code is intact?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, interface, ado.net

We have many stored procedures in MS SQL Server 2008. These are called by .NET code. Sometimes the procedures are called in multiple places.

When changing a stored procedure, e.g. adding a "mandatory" parameter, we obviously need to make sure that all calls from our .NET program are updated.

Is there any way, beside diligent analysis, to automatically check that the "interface" between the calling .NET code and the interfaces of the stored procedures is still intact?

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you unit testing your DB layer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest employing codegeneration for such task. There is [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that you can use to generate "interface" between stored procedures and your code. You can use partial classes to separate generated code from hand-written so there should be no problem here.

And if you are right about "We have many stored procedures in MS SQL Server 2008" then investments in codegeneration will return quickly.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem on our project with Oracle DB. To make sure that everything is up-to-date we have a set of integration tests which call every stored procedure and verifies result.

Continuous Integration server (TeamCity in our case) creates test DB every night and runs tests on it.